# For some reason my code just display one time, when I refresh the page i am starting to get errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SingleUser = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const { username } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSingleUser = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          `https://api.chess.com/pub/player/${username}/stats`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        const heroesArray = Object.values(data);
        setUser(heroesArray);
        console.log(heroesArray[0].last);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    getSingleUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <h1>Rapid Chess</h1>
        <p>Current Rating: {user[0].last.rating}</p>
        <p>Best Rating: {user[0].best.rating} </p>
        <div>
          <p>Wins: {user[0].record.win} </p>
          <p>Losses: {user[0].record.loss} </p>
          <p>Draws: {user[0].record.draw} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    
    </section>
  );
};

export default SingleUser;
```

For some reason my code just display one time, when I refresh the page i am starting to get errors. I think it is something about useEffect but I don't know

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'last') . I get these  error.

Comment: Could you please check this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , this will help you to ask a better question.

Answer (score 0):

When your are dealing with data coming from api you should use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), because the data may or may not come:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SingleUser = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const { username } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSingleUser = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          `https://api.chess.com/pub/player/${username}/stats`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        const heroesArray = Object.values(data);
        setUser(heroesArray);
        console.log(heroesArray?.[0]?.last);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    getSingleUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <h1>Rapid Chess</h1>
        <p>Current Rating: {user?.[0]?.last?.rating}</p>
        <p>Best Rating: {user?.[0]?.best?.rating} </p>
        <div>
          <p>Wins: {user?.[0]?.record?.win} </p>
          <p>Losses: {user?.[0]?.record?.loss} </p>
          <p>Draws: {user?.[0]?.record?.draw} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    
    </section>
  );
};

export default SingleUser;
```